# how to connect wires of step motor 42BYGH403 to driver drv8825 pins

Tags: arduino-uno

I am new to step motor and its driver. I bought a step motor 42BYGH403 with leads : yellow-red-green-blue.

### [image: Heading]

and I want to connect this wires to related pins on driver drv8825. such as:
[image]

but i don't know which color (lead)  should be connected to which pin A1, A2, B1 or B2?

Answer (score 1):

Well one option is to try different things and see what happens.

On the motor driver data sheet, there should be a diagram somewhere that looks similar to the one shown above, with the wires from `A1`, `A2`, etc going into the motor, and it should show the wire color. Or maybe something referencing phase A/B. (From what I recall, red and blue go together on a similar motor, but check that.) I think as long as the connected wires are the same as in the data sheet, the motor should turn.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but there is no information on datasheet about that. [link] (https://www.pololu.com/file/0J590/drv8825.pdf).

Comment: That's the data sheet for the motor controller, do you have one for the motor itself?

Comment: No, unfortunately I couldn't  find that.

Comment: Try hooking up red to A1, blue to A2, green to B1, and yellow to B2, and see what happens.

Comment: Then sorry, I got nothing. There's only 24 possible combinations though, if you have no other leads. (And of course, made sure everything else is working before that)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I test all combination and find: yellow->B2, blue->B1, red->A1 and green->A2.